# Calculating inter-rater reliability for only one variable

Tags: r, correlation, survey

I am trying to calculate how reliably zoo keepers rated each adjective on a survey I sent regarding panda behaviour.

For keepers that rated more than one panda, I was planning on calculating Kendall’s W, but while this works for certain values it doesn’t work for others.

```
install.packages("irr")

Keeper_a <- c(3, 3)

Keeper_b <- c(3, 3)

Keeper_c <- c(4, 4)

df <- data.frame(Keeper_a, Keeper_b, Keeper_c) 

kendall(df, correct = TRUE)

 Subjects = 2 
 Raters = 3 
 Wt = NaN 

 Chisq(1) = NaN 
 p-value = NaN
```

(for example for these I get NaN). Instead, here I get a reasonable result:

```
Keeper_a <- c(4, 3)

Keeper_b <- c(1, 2)

Keeper_c <- c(3, 4)

df <- data.frame(Keeper_a, Keeper_b, Keeper_c) 

kendall(df, correct = TRUE)

Subjects = 2 
Raters = 3 
   Wt = 0.111 

Chisq(1) = 0.333 
p-value = 0.564
```

Instead, for keepers that only rated one panda, I am not sure how to correlate them on a single adjective as the tests that I’ve tried need at least one other variable. While I believe I could do a Mann-Whitney U test on the pandas that were rated by two keepers, how would I do this for those that were rated by 4?

I hope this makes sense and someone has some insight!

Comment: does your data have more than 2 rows?

Comment: It depends on the zoo. In some cases, there was only one individual and so there is only one row. I've seen studies that have calculated reliability per adjective per individual animal and I can't figure out how

Comment: does it work when the data has more than say 10 rows?

Comment: Yes, I calculated Kendall's W per for all ratings on every behaviour and I had no issues with that. Could it not be possible due to the small sample size?

Answer (score 0):

From `?Kendall`

```
An error is returned if length(x) is less than 3.
```

---

EDIT: from your updated question, there is no variability in your first example:

```
Keeper_a <- c(3, 3)
Keeper_b <- c(3, 3)
Keeper_c <- c(4, 4)
```

I strongly suspect that is the reason

Comment: but it works when I have the same amount but with different values

Comment: I would suggest to edit your question, showing such a case

Comment: Good point, sorry!

Comment: no problem, see edits

Comment: But shouldn't the test highlight reliability in rating? and keeper c rated differently compared to the other two. I apologize if I'm not understanding or missing something, this is all quite new to me!